# Why has Microsoft removed the select all option on Reporting Services 2008?

Tags: reporting-services

When creating a subscription on reporting services 2008 one is unable to select all on the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it was ever there but [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrishays/archive/2006/04/18/AllParameterValueRedux.aspx) is a way to do it.